# How to compare 2 boolean values in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to compare to boolean value in a `if`.
I would like to do something like this:

```
value1 = false;
value2 = true;

if (value1 === value2) {
  ... Some code ...
}
```

In JAVA you can use `Boolean.compare(boolean a, boolean b)`, but **I can't find something equal** in TypeScript.
For context, [`Boolean.compare(boolean a, boolean b)` returns](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-compare-method-in-java-with-examples/):

- 0 if `a` is equal to `b`,
- a negative value if `a` is false and `b` is true,
- a positive value if `a` is true and `b` is false.

Thanks for you help

Edited: to show the message I get

[image]

This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'true' and 'false' have no overlap

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote?

Comment: `===` *is* how to compare two boolean values.

Comment: `===` checks for equality. `Boolean.compare` checks for ordering (returns less than zero if `a` is `false` and `b` is `true`, zero if they are equal or more than zero if `a` is `true` and `b` is false - is that the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: What you've written works perfectly, I suppose you could use `if ((value1  && value2) || (!value1 && !value2))`

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a description for `Boolean.compare` to your question since it seems you're being downvoted due to being misunderstood.

Comment: @Etheryte Thanks, I think guys love download people that learn the language and try to undestand

Comment: dw someone and I upvoted you so at least you won't lose reputation

Comment: What you have there is a linter error; the error message should be clear: the values are hardcoded, so there's no point in comparing them in the first place. It's not a sytax error at all. Assign true or false randomly to at least one value, and the linter error will disappear. (I downvoted you because before you edited the question is was completely unclear what your actual issue is; the question also gave the impression that you gave up way too soon and posted here, instead of, say, trying to run the code and realizing that it will indeed run)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, I know it :). And it shows me that it does not do like Boolean.compare()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript [doesn't have](https://www.karltarvas.com/2020/12/19/javascript-boolean-compare.html) a builtin that's comparable to Java's [`Boolean.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compare(boolean,%20boolean)). In fact, [the Boolean class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) has nearly nothing in it, outside the constructor, `toString()` and `valueOf()`.

If you want to replicate the functionality yourself, you can use [the `Number` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

```
function booleanCompare(a: boolean, b: boolean) {
    return Number(a) - Number(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) Its exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to reach all possible outcommings:

```
const Result = {
  first: 0, // A: 0, B 0
  second: 1, // A: 1, B 0
  third: -1, // A: 0, B 1
  forth: 2, // A: 1, B 1
  get: (A: boolean, B: boolean) => (Number(A) - Number(B))
}

const f = () => {
  const A = true;
  const B = true;

  switch(Result.get(A, B)) {
    case Result.first:
      // To something
      break;
    case Result.second:
      // To something
      break;
    case Result.third:
      // To something
      break;
    case Result.forth:
      // To something
  }
}
```